# How to convert char* to string *?

Tags: c++

Tell me how to create different strings in one pointer string like array.
see  following two program. 1st one give an errors. what is wrong here?
Kindly correct it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string *j={"nilesh",
                "rohit",
                "samir",};

    cout<<j<<endl;
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 4;
int main ()
{
    char *names[] = {"Zara Ali","Hina Ali","Nuha Ali","Sara Ali",};
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No body will answer this nor will I...You should start reading...for your reference... http://ideone.com/Q7Zsme

Comment: You should probably start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

Write simply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s[] = { "nilesh", "rohit", "samir", };

    for ( const string &t : s ) cout << t << endl;
}
```

Also instead of the array you could use standard class `std::vector<std::string>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "nilesh", "rohit", "samir", };

    for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not try it in this way ?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string j[]={"nilesh",
                "rohit",
                "samir"};

    cout<<j<<endl;
}
```

Printing j directly wont print all the three names. You need to print `j[0], j[1] ...`